# How to migrate nodes from a dev site to a production site?

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting, migrations

I have a staging site and a production site.

For an error some nodes was updated on the production site and now I have to update it but, if I will do that I will lose the production site changes.

What is the best [and faster] approach to migrate some nodes from production to staging before migrate staging to production?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) to export your nodes from dev and then re-import them on your live site.

Node Export provides several ways to export nodes:

- Through a tab that appears on the node page.
- Using update options on the Content page.
- In a command line using Drush.
- Using the Features module.
- Using the Views Bulk Operations module.

and the Node export package comes with the following formats:

- JSON
- Drupal var export
- Node code
- CSV
- Serialize
- XML